# WPF binding DataGrid to CollectionViewSource: working via DataContext, empty via ItemsSource; difference?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datacontext, itemssource

Consider the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static c:ViewModel.Instance}}"
    >
<Grid>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding ItemsViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />

</Grid>
```

and the view model:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public static ViewModel Instance { get; set; }

    static ViewModel()
    {
        Instance = new ViewModel();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
    public CollectionViewSource ItemsViewSource { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        ItemsViewSource = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Items };
        Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { FirstName = "test", LastName = "test" });
    }
}
```

This code is working, but if I change

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding ItemsViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

to

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsViewSource}" />`
```

DataGrid does not bind, it is empty.

What is the difference between these two bindings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all for second option to work, you need to bind with `CollectionViewSource.View` property.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsViewSource.View}" />
```

When you bind DataContext of dataGrid to CollectionViewSource, ***dataGrid internally do value conversion from CollectionViewSource to ICollectionView (ListCollectionView in your case)*** but when you asked it explicitly to bind to CollectionViewSource, it doesn't do default value conversion. You can verify this by putting converter in your binding.

Comment: Why then, if I bind `ItemsSource` to `CollectionViewSource` like that: `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}"` (where cvsTasks is instance of `CollectionViewSource` - see example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it works as well? 
I.e. why sometimes DataGrid does value conversion from CollectionViewSource to ICollectionView, and sometimes it does not?

Comment: Yeah I know dataGrid do value conversion that time as well. For second Why, you have to look into WPF code via reflection that in what cases they do value conversion.